# node scp2 speed issue?

Tags: node.js, docker, file-transfer, scp

I'm using a node server to check and transfer file from one server (EC2 instance) to another (commercial server farm) using scp2.

```
copyFile(tmpZip, remotepath, opts) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const Client = require('scp2').Client;
  const client = new Client(opts);
  let perc = 0;
  client.on('transfer', (buffer, uploaded, total) => {
    const currentPerc = Math.round(uploaded * 100 / total);
    if (currentPerc > perc) {
      perc = currentPerc;
      console.log('[ %s ] - [ %s ] Copied %s%', new Date(), tmpZip, perc);
    }
  });
  console.log('[ %s ] Copy started %s', new Date(), tmpZip);
  client.upload(tmpZip, remotepath, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('[ %s ]Copy failed ', tmpZip, err);
      reject(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('[ %s ]File copied!', tmpZip);
    resolve();
  });
});
}
```

my opts is:

```
const opts = {
            host,
            username,
            privateKey: Buffer.from(privateKey)
          };
          if (passphrase) {
            opts.passphrase = passphrase;
          }
```

My problem is that the Node server takes about 20 minutes to transfer (only transfer, without check) 1GB file, while a normal bash scp takes only 1 minute.
Is there any scp2 known issue ?

More info:
The Node server is inside a docker container on a ubuntu 16.04 server, no more network traffic is generated during the process.